# Nginx not loading index.php

Tags: php, nginx

I'm using nginx and php5-fpm in my ubuntu pc, my site is not loading in browser i have configured everything, but i'm getting 500 internal server error in browser console when i was run my index.php.

This is my code (etc/nginx/sites-available/default)

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html/Inwiter;
index index.php index.htm index.html;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to check the error log? If you don't have one enabled you should add the following to your configuration: `error_log logs/error.log warn;`

Comment: This my nginx error log:  2015/08/31 17:54:47 [error] 3109#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"

Comment: I'm thinking that perhaps `php5-fpm` isn't running? Try to restart it by executing `sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart` or `sudo service php5-fpm start`. You also may try to restart `nginx`

Answer (score 0):

Few days back i also faced this kind of issue (not exactly this issue) that time i was added allow accessToken in my configuration file then it was fine for me.
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

Comment: Add just below the                                                                                  listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;                                                                   lines in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As the log you provided, nginx still try to use `fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000` as fastcgi_pass .

Did you restart nginx or reload configuration after modification ?

Besides, please check configuration file in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/`.

There must be a line with `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.

I recommend you to remove `ipv6only=on` , and try following sample configuraion:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```